# Adding validation to Edittexts in Fragment

Tags: android

I'm trying to add validation to `EditText` in `Fragment` but my application is crashing.  I tried to use `getActivity()` also in place of this still facing the same issue.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.AwesomeValidation;
import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.ValidationStyle;

public class TestFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    EditText ET_input_first_name, ET_input_last_name, ET_input_email, ET_input_contact, ET_comments;
    String   first_name, last_name, email , contact , comments;

    private Button buttonSubmit;
    private AwesomeValidation awesomeValidation;

    public TestFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = null;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);

        ET_input_first_name = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_first_name);
        ET_input_last_name = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_last_name);
        ET_input_email = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        ET_input_contact = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_contact);
        ET_comments = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.comments);

        awesomeValidation = new AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.BASIC);
        buttonSubmit = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_test_drive);

        //adding validation to edittexts
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this , R.id.input_first_name, "^[A-Za-z\\s]{1,}[\\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\\s]{0,}$", R.string.nameerror);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.input_last_name, "^[A-Za-z\\s]{1,}[\\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\\s]{0,}$", R.string.nameerror);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.input_email, Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS, R.string.nameerror);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.input_contact, "^[2-9]{2}[0-9]{8}$", R.string.nameerror);

        buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }
    private void submitForm() {
        if (awesomeValidation.validate()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Validation Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        submitForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, add your stack trace if you need help debugging a crash.

Comment: Using my phone to debug the application, How to get logcat from that. I tried the above method in Activity its working, But on fragment its getting crashed.

Comment: Can you post your addValidation method? And your logcat would also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

To do this there are 2 ways: use this code in fragment

1) `EditText et = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText)`

2) Make your edittext `public static` in your activity and initialize it only there. Then to use in fragment just write `YourActivity.edittext.getText().toString()`. It will work